# how to write where condition in relation table in Laravel in query

Tags: laravel, relation

I have 3 table that is `Resort`, `Booking`, `Expense`, these tables are join with relation. the code is given below,

```php
$resorts = Resort::where('status',1)->with('bookings')->withSum('bookings', 'amount')
        ->with('expenses')->withSum('expenses', 'amount')->get();
```

I want to sort this table using the `date` field. how could I use the `wherebetween` in this query for bookings and expense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass array in  `with()` like this

```php
$resorts = Resort::where('status', 1)
    ->with(
        ['bookings' => function ($q) {
            $q->wherebetween('colName', ['startDate','endDate']);
        }]
    )->withSum('bookings', 'amount')
    ->with(
        ['expenses' => function ($q) {
            $q->wherebetween('colName', ['startDate','endDate']);
        }]
    )->withSum('expenses', 'amount')
    ->get();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: use this code the i got the error

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\IncomeExpenseController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}()

Comment: `IncomeExpenseController` ? put this code as well then i can tell what is this error